# Laravel runs dev assets nonmatter what on production server after I ran npm run dev accidentally

Tags: laravel, npm, vite, npm-package

I ran npm run dev on the server with Laravel 9 using Vite and Tailwind. Now when I run npm run build it is still trying to load the css and javascript files from a domain 127.0.0.1. I can not get it back to reading the manifest.json in the build folder and loading those files.

npm run build runs without any errors,

however the npm run dev was throwing errors and I killed the process and double cheked using ps aux, and pkill commands.

I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

nvm, for some reason the command

```
pkill npm
```

does not work I had to use

```
kill -9 [process-id]
```

and it worked.